# Returning HTML in JSON Format and Calling a Function

Tags: javascript, json, function

I'm not even sure if this is possible or not, but I am trying to display an HTML page, formatted as JSON, and then call a function whenever the user clicks on a button inside of this returned HTML. I know this is weird, but this is the way the customer wants it. Can anyone tell me if this is even possible? And also, I already have the page displaying correctly. The only issue is actually executing a function when the user clicks a button on this page.

```
    {
    "responseHTML": "<script>console.log('TEST')</script><div><button onclick='test()'></button></div>"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `display an HTML page, formatted as JSON`

Comment: It is definitely weird but possible. So what you can do is receive html as json and then append it to body element

$('body').append(data.responseHTML);

Comment: @MohsinMehmood The `script` contents won't execute that way. A new `script` element must be created via the DOM and a text node created for it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think the goal is to render the html received as json. So if there is a method defined inside scripts tag it will be called on button click e.g <button onclick='test()'></button>. You are right about executing console.log statement inside scripts tag

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I know what the goal is. It won't be accomplished by simply appending the response to the body.

Comment: I appreciate all of your feedback. I already have the JSON returning fine, and the page displays as expected. The only problem I'm having is actually executing a function from within this JSON. I would have posted the full code, but since it's for a client I'm not sure that would be the best thing for me to do.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your question to mean that the API in question returns "a complete HTML page" as part of a JSON-encoded payload. *(Which is actually a fairly-common thing to do.)*

My candid answer is that this should be done by code that is added on the ''server'' side. (That is to say, *the server* should be modified to return HTML that includes the necessary JavaScript voodoo.)  Meanwhile, *the client* should require no change.

Here's why: *"once your Alice jumps down that rabbit-hole, there's just no way out."* You wind up creating extremely *fragile* code on one side or the other which becomes a maintenance nightmare.  Therefore, practice the principle of "separation of concerns."  The server's concern is to provide the appropriate HTML; the client's concern is merely to display it.  Keep it that way.

Comment: You have some good points. By "client", I just meant the people I'm writing this code for. I'm doing this for my job, and unfortunately, I'm not in a position where I have direct access to speak with the clients to suggest alternatives. The deadline is quickly approaching, and the project manager is really getting on my case about this. I'm tempted to just say it's not possible to do, but I just wanted to try and confirm that. Thank you!

Comment: perhaps 'customer' would be a better term than 'client' as 'client' is over-loaded...